# Pythin Tkinter - size frames according to image size

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

im currently building a pdf editing tool with python and tkinter. To be precise, im using CustomTkinter for a more modern look and feel. Here is my Code:

```
from math import sqrt, ceil, floor
from tkinter import *  
from customtkinter import *
import crossfiledialog
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import darkdetect
from merge_pdf import merge_pdfs

if darkdetect.isLight():
    set_appearance_mode("light")
else:
    set_appearance_mode("dark")
    
set_default_color_theme("blue")

class PDF_Display(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, width, image, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.image_source = image
        
        wpercent = (width/float(self.image_source.size[0]))
        self.img_height = int((float(self.image_source.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
        self.image = CTkImage(light_image=self.image_source, size=(width,self.img_height))
        self.label = CTkLabel(master=self, image=self.image, text="")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=5, pady=5)
        
        self.button_frame = CTkFrame(master=self)
        self.button_left = CTkButton(master=self.button_frame, text="<")
        self.button_right = CTkButton(master=self.button_frame, text=">")
        self.button_delete = CTkButton(master=self.button_frame, text="del")

        self.rowconfigure([0, 1], weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.button_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.button_frame.columnconfigure([0, 1, 2], weight=1)

    def resize_image(self, width):
        wpercent = (width/float(self.image_source.size[0]))
        self.img_height = int((float(self.image_source.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
        self.image = CTkImage(light_image=self.image_source, size=(width,self.img_height))
        self.label = CTkLabel(master=self, image=self.image, text="")
        self.label.grid_forget()
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=5, pady=5)

        

class Display_Frame(CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.pdf_displays = []
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.resize_displays)
        
    def add_displays(self, images):
        """Add new displays."""
        
        length = ceil(sqrt(len(images)))
        for img in images:
            self.pdf_displays.append(PDF_Display(master=self, width=floor(self.winfo_width()/length)-length*10, image=img, border_width = 1))
            
        self.display()
    
    def load_displays(self, images):
        """Reload displays."""
        
        self.clear()
        self.add_displays(images)
        
    def display(self):
        """Update displayed displays."""
        
        for display in self.pdf_displays:
            display.grid_forget()
        
        length = ceil(sqrt(len(self.pdf_displays)))
        column_index = 0
        row_index = 0
        while row_index < length:
            while row_index*length+column_index < len(self.pdf_displays) and column_index < length:
                self.pdf_displays[row_index*length+column_index].grid(row=row_index, column=column_index, sticky="nsew", padx=5, pady=5)
                column_index += 1
            row_index += 1
            column_index = 0
            
        for i in range(length):
            self.columnconfigure(i, minsize=floor(self.winfo_width()/length), weight=1)
            #self.rowconfigure(i, minsize=50, weight=1)
            
    def clear(self):
        """Clear display widges."""
        
        for display in self.pdf_displays:
            display.grid_forget()
        self.pdf_displays = []

    def resize_displays(self, event):
        length = ceil(sqrt(len(self.pdf_displays)))
        for display in self.pdf_displays:
            display.resize_image(floor(event.width/length)-length*10)
        

class App(CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.paths = []
        self.images = []
        self.title("PDF Merger")
        self.rowconfigure(0, minsize=100, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, minsize=50, weight=1)
        self.frame_left = CTkFrame(master=self, border_width=2,fg_color=("Grey","Grey"))
        self.frame_right = Display_Frame(master=self, width=400, height=300, corner_radius=0, fg_color="transparent")
        self.frame_left.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky="ns", padx=5, pady=5)
        self.frame_right.grid(row=0, column=1,sticky="nsew")
        
        button_open = CTkButton(master=self.frame_left, text="Open PDF", command=self.open_files)
        button_append = CTkButton(master=self.frame_left, text="Append PDF", command=self.append_files)
        button_save = CTkButton(master=self.frame_left, text="Save PDF", command=self.save_file)
        button_clear = CTkButton(master=self.frame_left, text="Clear", command=self.clear)

        button_open.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
        button_append.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
        button_save.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
        button_clear.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
        
    def open_files(self):
        """Open a files for editing."""
        
        self.clear()
        self.append_files()
    
    def append_files(self):
        """Append file for editing."""
        
        tmp_paths = crossfiledialog.open_multiple(title="Open PDF", filter={"PDF-Files": "*.pdf", "All Files": ["*.*"]})
        for path in tmp_paths:
            self.images += convert_from_path(path)
            
        self.paths += tmp_paths
        self.frame_right.load_displays(self.images)
    
    def save_file(self):
        """Save file after editing."""
        
        filepath = crossfiledialog.save_file("Save PDF")
        merge_pdfs(self.paths, range(len(self.images)), filepath)
        
    def clear(self):
        """Clear all opend files."""
        
        self.paths = []
        self.images = []
        self.frame_right.clear()


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

The above code in tested on linux mint, but it should be compatible with other linux distributions and Windows.
Merge_pdfs is a function I wrote which does the computation, should not concern you.

My Problem is that I want to show multiple pdf pages in the frame_right of my App. The PDF_Display class should take care of displaying a single pdf page together with three buttons in a frame. The pdf page is saved as an PIL image. This image should be resized so that the PDF_Display widges fill up the whole width of my Display_Frame instance. All PDF_Display instances and their image should also resize if the width of the window changes. So I want to resize according to the width and preserve the ratio of the image. I managed to resize the images, but the height of the PDF_Display widges does not get smaller if I make he overall window smaller.

frame_left of App should only if the height if the window changes.

As you can see, I already tried `bind("<Configure>",...)` and I managed to resize the images themself. But the frame does not contract if the images are scaled back, which is my main problem.

Comment: whilst wildcard imports are allowed, for clarity it is best to avoid them:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)